# Powershell Timestamp

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am trying to export a log to a csv file in powershell but I am having difficulty placing a timestamp for each "Log" within the file. I can export the log into a csv file, but for each action it logs I would like an individual timestamp. For example, I would like the output below in my csv file to look like this and have a timestamp for each (note the timestamp before the action)

```
2020/02/13 93520 - Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\03042019-PC\C$\Users\*\AppData\Local\Apps\Test\21.txt". 

2020/02/13 93522 - Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\\03052019-PC\C$\Users\*\AppData\Local\Apps\Test\51.txt".
```

Any help would be appreciated! Here is what I have so far: (from researching online)

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory


$timestamp = "LogFile"

$filepath = "C:\$timestamp.csv"


#$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "*-PC"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "03*2019-PC"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 

# Loop through users and delete the file

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {

    $path = "\\$Computer\C$\Users\*\AppData\Local\Apps\Test\*"
    $result = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Remove-Item -force -verbose *>> $filepath 
} 


$upperLimit = [datetime]::MaxValue #replace with your own date
$lowerLimit = [datetime]::MinValue #replace with your own date

$log | foreach {
$dateAsText = ($_ -split '\s',2)[0]
try
{
$date = [datetime]::Parse($dateAsText)
if (($lowerLimit -lt $date) -and ($date -lt $upperLimit))
{
$_ #output the current item because it belongs to the requested time frame
}
}
catch [InvalidOperationException]
{
#date is malformed (maybe the line is empty or there is a typo), skip it
}
}
```

Comment: I note your program won't work as written. You're piping the contents of $log into the foreach, but the variable $log is never loaded with data. In any case, see my answer for how to create a timestamp for each log entry

Comment: Got your program working - see **Update** at the bottom of my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you want the timestamp to be the current date and time, although I'm not sure what the 5-digit number means, e.g., the digits `93520` in your example are what?

> 2020/02/13 93520 - Performing the operation "Remove File" on target
> "\03042019-PC\C$\Users*\AppData\Local\Apps\Test\21.txt".

Anyway, if you want a date + time stamp with the current date and time, just generate and format it using the `get-date` cmdlet and concatenate it to your log text using a formatted string. [More on formatted string here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-).

Example follows. Note: `hh:mm:ss tt` outputs 12-hour time with AM/PM. `HH:mm:ss` outputs 24-hour time

**CODE**

```
cls

$fakeLogText = '93520 - Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\03042019-PC\C$\Users*\AppData\Local\Apps\Test\21.txt'
$output = "{0} {1}" -f (get-date -f "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt"), $fakeLogText
$output

$fakeLogText = '93522 - Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "\03052019-PC\C$\Users*\AppData\Local\Apps\Test\51.txt'
$output = "{0} {1}" -f (get-date -f "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt"), $fakeLogText
$output
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Also, I note your program won't work as written. You're piping the contents of `$log` into the foreach, but the variable $log is never loaded with data

**UPDATE - Working Program**

This program does what I think you want it to do. Comment out my temporary line of code `$Computers = ("MyComputer1", "MyComputer2")` and uncomment the call to `Get-ADComputer` that you want

```
cls

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$allUsersTextFileList = @()

#$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "03*2019-PC"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$Computers = ("MyComputer1", "MyComputer2")

# Loop through users and delete their txt files

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) 
{
    #make a list of users
    $userPathList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$Computer\C$\Users\")

    foreach ($userPath in $userPathList)
    {
        #for this user, make a path to their txt files
        $userTestFolderPath = ("{0}\AppData\Local\Apps\Test" -f $userPath.Fullname)

        #if the path exists, make list of all txt files in the \Test folder
        if (test-path -LiteralPath $userTestFolderPath -PathType Container)
        {
            $userTextFileList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $userTestFolderPath -Filter *.txt)

            #add this user's list to the "all users" list
            $allUsersTextFileList += $userTextFileList
        }
    }
} 

$itemList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$itemList.clear()
$item = [ordered]@{} 

foreach ($textFile in $allUsersTextFileList)
{
    Remove-Item -force -verbose -LiteralPath $textFile.Fullname 

    $item.Date = (get-date -f "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt")
    $item.File = "Performing the operation 'Remove File' on target {0}" -f $textFile.Fullname 
    $itemList.add((New-Object PSObject -Property $item)) | out-null
}

$itemList | Export-Csv -LiteralPath "C:\temp\logFile.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I didn't think about adding in the Foreach for the users...that is a good idea. I tested it on my system and it worked as well! the logfile had a timestamp on every action too. (I have been trying to avoid going to the forum for a solution as I wanted to solve it myself but the past two days have been frustrating and I'm on a time schedule lol) Thank you!!!

Comment: @ggorlen: Yes, you're correct. Good catch. I also had the format code for minutes wrong. I update the code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about filters. You can create one in powershell using a command such as

```
PS> filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format o): $_"}
```

Note, the name "timestamp" is arbitrary. You can call it just about anything
then just pipe whatever command into it.
Use additional pipe to Tee-object to record output to a file

```
PS> $file = "MyCool.log"

PS> my_cool_command | timestamp |  Tee-object -FilePath  $file
```